# How to make some code wait for a function to complete?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node server, this is the login route. I am trying to send a response after checking if the user exists in the DB and if the password match the hash value. I am using a custom flag but the code where I check for the value is executed before the value can be changed.

```
router.route('/login').post( (req,res) => {
        User.findOne({email: req.body.email} ,(err,user) => {
            let check = false
            if(!user){
                return res.json({
                    loginSuccess:false,
                    message : "Invalid Email or Password"
                })
            }
            user.comparePassword(req.body.password,(err, isMatch)=> {
                if(err){
                    return res.json({
                        loginSuccess : false,
                        message : "Can't Login. Try Again!"
                    })
                };
                if(isMatch){
                    check = true
                }
            })
    
            if(!check){
                return res.json({
                    loginSuccess : false,
                    message : "Invalid Eail or Password"
                })
            }
            
            user.generateToken((err, user) => {
                if(err) {
                    return res.status(400).send(err)
                }
                else{
                res.cookie('x_auth' , user.token)
                .status(200)
                .json({
                    user : user,
                    loginSuccess:true 
                })
                }
            })
    
        })
    })
```

In the code above, how can I make

```
if(!check){
                return res.json({
                    loginSuccess : false,
                    message : "Invalid Eail or Password"
                })
            }
```

Wait for this:

```
user.comparePassword(req.body.password,(err, isMatch)=> {
                if(err){
                    return res.json({
                        loginSuccess : false,
                        message : "Can't Login. Try Again!"
                    })
                };
                if(isMatch){
                    check = true
                }
            })
```

Actually the code below executes first before the flag is changed, but I want it to wait, so it can decide on the new value of `check`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do your checking inside the callback.

```js
router.route('/login').post((req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, user) => {
        if (!user) {
            return res.json({
                loginSuccess: false,
                message: "Invalid Email or Password"
            })
        }
        user.comparePassword(req.body.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                    loginSuccess: false,
                    message: "Can't Login. Try Again!"
                })
            };
            if (!isMatch) {
                return res.json({
                    loginSuccess: false,
                    message: "Invalid Eail or Password"
                })
            }
            user.generateToken((err, user) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).send(err)
                }
                else {
                    res.cookie('x_auth', user.token)
                        .status(200)
                        .json({
                            user: user,
                            loginSuccess: true
                        })
                }
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert that callback into promise:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    user.comparePassword(req.body.password, (err, isMatch)=> {
       if(err){
           return res.json({
               loginSuccess : false,
               message : "Can't Login. Try Again!"
           });
       };
       if(isMatch){
           check = true;
           resolve();
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript's [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) API, where the executor function would execute your login and the `.then` and `.catch` would be executed after the promise's executor, depending on whether it was fulfilled. The documentation provides this example:

```
let myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // We call resolve(...) when what we were doing asynchronously was successful, and reject(...) when it failed.
  // In this example, we use setTimeout(...) to simulate async code. 
  // In reality, you will probably be using something like XHR or an HTML5 API.
  setTimeout( function() {
    resolve("Success!")  // Yay! Everything went well!
  }, 250) 
}) 

myFirstPromise.then((successMessage) => {
  // successMessage is whatever we passed in the resolve(...) function above.
  // It doesn't have to be a string, but if it is only a succeed message, it probably will be.
  console.log("Yay! " + successMessage) 
});
```

Basically you will need to resolve/reject the promise at the end of your login method. You can also resolve this with callbacks, as Duc Nguyen has already suggested, but in that case beware [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).